# How to Move an Image from Margin: Auto?

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I'm working on a responsive site and I have looked all over the web with no prevail.

I am trying to animate an image that has it's margins set to auto initially and then animate it to a specific position (i.e. to: margin-top: 4px & margin-left: 30px). Anything I do that gets it moving jumps because of the margin set to auto - but the image needs to be responsively in the middle horizontally for mobile devices as its initial state and animate smoothly.

HTML:

```
<div class="logoWrapper">
    <img class="logo" src="some.png"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logo {
    display: block;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    margin-top: 90px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 14;
    -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
    -o-transition: all .8s ease;
}
.logoShrink {
    margin-top: 4px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
.logoWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 15;
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('.logo').addClass('logoShrink');
```

I know this is an issue for many but nothing I can find works; Lets get a real solution here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. THNX!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to center the image with position: absolute and left: 50% and margin-left: -50%. It can be done because its parent is position: fixed.

```
.logo {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    margin-left: -45px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 90px;
    z-index: 14;
    -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
    -o-transition: all .8s ease;
}
```

After that, transitioning top, left and margin-left will do what you want.

Comment: Thnx but I have tried that. The image doesn't center on mobile devices. Its usually of by 40 to 80px. Don't get why.

Comment: Did you set the negative margin-left, too? Its function is to compensate a same deviation.

Comment: Honestly I don't remember coz I've tried so much with it. I'll look at that again.

Comment: It should work, I am sure. I don't understand, why on mobile happened deviation, if it were browser-dependant I had at least ideas. But this is your direction. BTW I suggest to stop positioning with margins, there is good top: and left:.

Comment: Thnx!!  I must have been missing something before.